# pyspark - Can I use substring of value as a key of groupBy() function?

Tags: pyspark, substring

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
datetime       | ID |
======================
20180201000000 | 275 |
20171231113024 | 534 |
20180201220000 | 275 |
20170205000000 | 28  |
```

what I want to do is to count by ID, monthly.

this way was perfactly worked :

1. add column of month by extracting from datetime column :

   `new_df = df.withColumn('month', df.datetime.substr(0,6))`
2. count by ID & month :

   `count_df = new_df.groupBy('ID','month').count()`

but is there a way to use substring of certain column values as an argument of `groupBy()` function? like :

```
`count_df = df.groupBy('ID', df.datetime.substr(0,6)).count()`
```

at least, this code didn't work.

if there exist the way to use substring of values, don't need to add new column and save much of resources(in case of big data).

but even if this approach is wrong, do you have a better idea to get same result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
>>> df.show()
+--------------+---+
|      datetime| id|
+--------------+---+
|20180201000000|275|
|20171231113024|534|
|20180201220000|275|
|20170205000000| 28|
+--------------+---+

>>> df.groupBy('id',df.datetime.substr(0,6)).agg(count('id')).show()
+---+-----------------------+---------+                                         
| id|substring(datetime,0,6)|count(id)|
+---+-----------------------+---------+
|275|                 201802|        2|
|534|                 201712|        1|
| 28|                 201702|        1|
+---+-----------------------+---------+
```